# Query in MySQL between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get some results from 2 tables in mysql.

The code for the mysql tables is

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b643c/1

In the link is the query that i made so i can get some results

Is there a better way to get the same results?

```
select ProductID, ProductTitle from cms_products
where ProductID not in(select ProductID from cms_group_products
where gID = 1000)
```

I tried this query and got the results that i wanted but i just want to know if the query is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query is fine, but I would use an anti-join.

```
SELECT cp.ProductID, ProductTitle
FROM cms_products cp
LEFT JOIN cms_group_products cgp ON (cp.ProductID = cgp.ProductID AND gID = 1000)
WHERE cgp.ProductID IS NULL
```